# Rails 3: using jquery-ui and generating tabs with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jquery-ui to get AJAX tabbing going. If seems like jquery-ui needs a specific url to go inside the `<a href="something.html">`, for example this i what I have:

```
 <div id="tabs">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="something-1.html" title="red">red</a></li>
    <li><a href="something-2.html" title="blue">green</a></li>
    <li><a href="something-3.html" title="last">blue</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div><!-- tabs -->
```

I have a route that looks like this:

```
match "/color/:color" => "pages#colors"
```

Ideally I would like to do something like this but it doesn't seem to work, page not found:

```
 <div id="tabs">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="/color/:red" title="red">red</a></li>
        <li><a href="/color/:green" title="blue">green</a></li>
        <li><a href="/color/:blue" title="last">blue</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div><!-- tabs -->
```

When I run "rake routes" theres no url helper for the /color/:color route either so i cant use that, which I've tested on other routes and works just fine. Do I need to create different routes that have a url helper for all the colors (which is over 10 colors)??

When I added color routes like this I got a url helper and made a new controller method for each color? but would need to be this redundant?

```
resources :users do
     member do
     get  :red, :green, :blue
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your urls should be "color/red", "color/green", "color/blue" etc. the :color in your match is just a variable that will be used so anything after "color/" in the url will be your :color variable.

that means you can access it in your controller as params[:color]